# I have idle3 installed but get a "Command 'idle3' not found" error when I try to invoke it

Tags: 18.04, python3, idle-python

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and have Python 3.6.7 installed.

I installed idle3 using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install idle3
```

which successfully installed the ide.

However, when I try to invoke it using `idle3`, I get the following error:

```
Command 'idle3' not found, did you mean:

  command 'idle' from deb idle

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

If I run `sudo apt-get install idle3` again, I get the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
idle3 is already the newest version (3.6.7-1~18.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
```

The command `which idle3` produces nothing.
What am I doing wrong and how do I get idle3, which is presumably installed on my system, to run.

Comment: You can see what got installed with `dpkg -L idle3`.

Comment: The output of this command is as follows:
`/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/idle3` Do I need to add the last path to my $PATH variable? It seems to be a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Python in Ubuntu 18.04 is Python 3.6.7. Typing the command `idle` in the terminal starts IDLE (using Python 3.6.7). You can also start idle and idle3 by clicking on their icons in the Dash.